# Need to move a power pole prior to new addition. Whats the cost?

Tags: construction, utilities, pole

I need to relocated a utility pole on a line going to a single home, pushing it back to the treeline. Once it is moved I need it to then go underground for the new pole to the house in the same location. How much does something like this cost? I need the pole move 100 ft. closer to it's source and then run underground about 200 ft. to the house. The meter would also need updating as well.[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is dependent on the specific utility and jurisdiction.

Comment: It will depend on your area, but expect to sell your first born.  Moving/replacing your own poles on your land can be very expensive.  Over 5000$.

Comment: When we had our overhead drop replaced with an underground feeder, they charged us by the foot and a little more for anything that had to cross public space (like the road out front). They were going to move the drop to the other corner of the house for us (for free, since we were adding on - cost would be covered by the increased power usage) and asked about underground on a whim. It was surprisingly reasonable, so we went underground. The best/only way to find out is call the PoCo and have someone come out and give you a quote.

Answer (score 7):

Check with the power company, I have seen it done for no cost to a lot of money, depending on your area and power company. The only good answer will be from the power company.